# Reproducing this plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I have two groups of patients. I want to have a plot for two groups of patients

something like this plot

[image]

I have such a data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(gene = c("18q", "4q", "21p", "21q", "5q", "22q", 
"17p", "3p", "9p", "4p", "9q", "19q", "10q", "15q", "16p", "19p", 
"1p", "18p", "16q", "8p", "21q", "4q", "18q", "21p", "1p", "3p", 
"4p", "17p", "5q", "16q", "18p", "14q", "19p", "20q"), CNV = c("Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Amplification"), log10_pvalue = c(5.974694135, 
5.73754891, 4.995678626, 4.970616222, 4.793174124, 4.793174124, 
4.109020403, 3.524328812, 3.524328812, 2.823908741, 2.567030709, 
2.186419011, 1.769551079, 1.59345982, 1.59345982, 1.59345982, 
1.416801226, 1.195860568, 1.094743951, 1.087777943, 4.083019953, 
3.826813732, 3.826813732, 3.826813732, 2.675717545, 2.675717545, 
2.675717545, 2.342944147, 2.084072788, 1.850780887, 1.659555885, 
1.197226275, 1.197226275, 1.88941029), Percentage_altered = c(0.61, 
0.53, 0.61, 0.56, 0.44, 0.5, 0.5, 0.44, 0.5, 0.47, 0.39, 0.28, 
0.33, 0.31, 0.33, 0.31, 0.22, 0.36, 0.33, 0.33, 0.63, 0.52, 0.59, 
0.67, 0.26, 0.44, 0.52, 0.48, 0.33, 0.44, 0.44, 0.3, 0.33, 0.5
), group = c("Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Responders", "Responders", "Responders", "Responders", 
"Responders", "Responders", "Responders", "Responders", "Responders", 
"Responders", "Responders", "Responders", "Responders", "Responders"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L))
>
```

I have tried this code but does not give me what you have produced

```
df %>%
  mutate(net_frequency=ifelse(CNV == "Deletion", -Percentage_altered/100, Percentage_altered/100)) %>%
  crossing(., tibble(grp = c("Responders", "Non-Responders"))) %>%
  mutate(log10_pvalue = if_else(CNV == "Deletion", -log10_pvalue, log10_pvalue)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = log10_pvalue, y = net_frequency, color = log10_pvalue)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Percentage_altered)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=ifelse(log10_pvalue > -log10(0.05), gene, "")), force=10) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=2) +
  scale_color_distiller(type = "div") +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~grp)
```

I obtain such a plot but does not make sense

[image]

If you look, for both groups only information for responders are being plotted

Can you help with editing the code please

Comment: have a look at `?facet_wrap` or `?facet_grid`

Comment: Yes but I don't knowhow to define group1 and group2 in the data frame and ask for different colors for amplification and deletion in each group, for instance deletion with light blue for group1 and deletion with dark blue for group2

Comment: Can you explain more about how "Responders" and "Non-responders" are represented in your data?  Are those the same as what you're calling `group1` and `group2`?  I don't see anything like that in the `df` you posted.  I see you are saying you don't know how to define group1/2 in the data, but it's also not clear what you mean by that.  Do you know which entries in `df` belong to those two groups?

Comment: Yes they are group1 and group2. df is just for group1 and group2 would have the same data but not pasted here

Comment: Providing a solution to your problem requires `group1` and `group2` included in the same data frame.  It'd be helpful if you can edit your post to provide data that fully represents your problem space.

Comment: You can add a column named group to both of your dfs and the value for df1 is "group1" and the second is "group2". Then rowbind the dfs. You can use the same calls to plot and add `facet_wrap` as described above. For the group colors do you need a continuous scale or discrete values? If discrete, you can combine the CVN and group columns and use that as a variable to define your colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** Includes OP's updated data, now with two groups.
**Edit 2** Removing OP's original `geom_repel` filter, per comments.

Here's an approach which creates a divergent color scale by making all of the `CNV == 'Deletion'` values for `log10_pvalue` negative.  Paired with `facet_wrap()`, this achieves your goal.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(net_frequency=ifelse(CNV == "Deletion", -Percentage_altered/100, Percentage_altered/100),
         log10_pvalue = if_else(CNV == "Deletion", -log10_pvalue, log10_pvalue)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = log10_pvalue, y = net_frequency, color = log10_pvalue)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Percentage_altered)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=gene), force=10) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=2) +
  scale_color_distiller(type = "div") +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, why I get this error Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"
In addition: Warning message:
`mutate_()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7.0.
Please use `mutate()` instead.
See vignette('programming') for more help
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated. 
>

Comment: Try a fresh R environment, just load `library(tidyverse)`, then load the `df` you defined in your post.  Then run this code - it will produce the plot above.

Comment: Thank you so much @andrew_reece and the others. I have my main post by adding real information for both groups and creating group column but after trying your code I only get the information for one group on the plot. Can you look at the plot? Thank you

Comment: Note that the only reason `crossing()` was included (originally by @r2evans) was to simulate data for two groups.  Now that you have included two groups, just remove that section of the pipe - everything else runs correctly.  I'll update my answer to demonstrate with your newly-added data.

Comment: Thank you so much. I gort that, but why only 20q has a name? What should I do to every circle has a name as their names are in the df

Comment: This is a decision made in your original code, with `geom_text_repel()`.  You have a rule that sets circle labels as `""` if the `log10_pvalue` does not meet a certain threshold.  Just remove, or change, this rule, if you want more circles to have labels.

Comment: Thank you so much I remeved " " and I got this Error in ifelse(log10_pvalue > log10(0.05), gene) : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default

Comment: try `geom_text_repel(aes(label=gene), force=10)`.  but if you are having trouble with `ifelse` syntax and how it fits into your plotting function, i would suggest you take a bit more time to understand the code you started with.  running code you don't understand is a good way to run into unexpected errors.  start with `?ifelse`.

Comment: Sorry how I change your code in a way no negative values are on the Y or X axises?  Actually the lower part of Y axis should be negative because this is just deleted arms in percentage and no sense if this is negative. Also in X axis that should not be negative. I tried to remove - from the code but the plot re-designed.

Answer (score 1):

As @andrew_reece suggested, `facet_*` will help here.

Since we don't have any notion of "Responders" in the data, I'll blindly duplicate the data using `tidyr::crossing`.

Also, just for the sake of demonstration, I removed `theme_classic` in order to highlight the panes. (There is no problem with using it, I just wanted to make clear the difference.)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel) # geom_text_repel
library(tidyr)   # crossing
df %>%
  mutate(net_frequency=ifelse(CNV == "Deletion", -Percentage_altered/100, Percentage_altered/100)) %>%
  crossing(. tibble(resp = c("Responder", "Non-Responder"))) %>%
  ggplot(. aes(x=log10_pvalue, y=net_frequency)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Percentage_altered, color=log10_pvalue)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=ifelse(log10_pvalue > -log10(0.05), gene, "")), force=10) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=2) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ resp)
```

[image: faceted ggplot2]

As for *"different colors for two groups"*, it isn't really clear what you need. If you want (e.g.) the color scale to be "blues" for responders and "reds" for non-responders, then look at ggplot-extension packages such as `ggnewscale` or `ggrelayer`. (They aren't baked-in.)